# Pop-up bootstrap + angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying use bootstrap's pop up in my web page. I have included all necessary files to my app but I get this exception in firebug console:

```
Error: $modal is not a function $scope.addBook@http://localhost:8080/engineering-project-web/resources/angular-app/navigation_bar/naviBarCtrl.js:7:18 $parseFunctionCall@http://localhost:8080/engineering-project-web/resources/libs/angular.js:12332:15 ngEventHandler/</callback@http://localhost:8080/engineering-project-web/resources/libs/angular.js:21389:17 $RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$eval@http://localhost:8080/engineering-project-web/resources/libs/angular.js:14384:16 $RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$apply@http://localhost:8080/engineering-project-web/resources/libs/angular.js:14483:18 ngEventHandler/<@http://localhost:8080/engineering-project-web/resources/libs/angular.js:21394:17 n.event.dispatch@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js:3:6392 n.event.add/r.handle@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js:3:3202
```

There are my all included scripts:

```
<script src="<c:url value="/resources/libs/jquery.js" />"></script>

        <!-- Angular Scripts -->
        <script src="<c:url value="/resources/libs/angular.js" />"></script>
        <script src="<c:url value="/resources/libs/angular-animate.min.js" />"></script>
        <script src="<c:url value="/resources/libs/angular-route.js" />"></script>
        <script src="<c:url value="/resources/libs/angular-resource.js" />"></script>

        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <script src="<c:url value="/resources/libs/jquery-ui.custom.min.js" />"></script>
        <script src="<c:url value="/resources/libs/bootstrap.js"/>"></script>
        <script src="<c:url value="/resources/libs/ui-bootstrap.js"/>"></script>    

        <!-- Controlers -->
        <script src="<c:url value="/resources/angular-app/main/AppCtrl.js" />"></script>
        <script src="<c:url value="/resources/angular-app/home/homeCtrl.js" />"></script>
        <script src="<c:url value="/resources/angular-app/navigation_bar/naviBarCtrl.js" />"></script>

        <!-- Services -->
        <script src="<c:url value="/resources/angular-app/home/homeSrvc.js" />"></script>   

        <!-- Directives -->
        <script src="<c:url value="/resources/angular-app/main/directives.js" />"></script>

        <!-- CSS -->
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="/resources/css/main.css" />" />   
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="/resources/angular-app/home/home.css" />" />  
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="/resources/css/bootstrap.css"/>">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="/resources/css/bootstrap-theme.css"/>">

        <!-- IE -->
        <script src="<c:url value="/resources/libs/html5.js" />"></script>
        <script src="<c:url value="/resources/libs/respond.js" />"></script>
        <script src="<c:url value="/resources/libs/css3-mediaqueries.js" />"></script>
```

This is my main angular's module:

```
var appModule = angular.module('frontendApp', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap']);


appModule.controller('AppCtrl' , ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.init = function() {
        $scope.baseUrl = "/engineering-project-web/resources/angular-app";
    };
}]);
```

And this is controller wherein I am trying turn on pop up.

```
appModule.controller('NaviBarCtrl', ['$scope', '$modal',  function ($scope, $modal) {

    $scope.addBook = function(){
        $scope.popup = $modal({
            scope : $scope,
            template : 'resources/angular-app/popups/AddTrainingUser.html',
            show : true
        });
    }

  }]);
```

Comment: in NaviBarCtrl change to $modal.open

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your $modal service is imported correctly; be sure you are calling the function to open it.

Try this:

```
    $scope.popup = $modal.open({
        scope : $scope,
        template : 'resources/angular-app/popups/AddTrainingUser.html',
        show : true
    });
```

Comment: Your suggestion is helpfull but now this script don't load my template.

Comment: What is the error you are seeing? Confirm 'resources/angular-app/popups/AddTrainingUser.html' is the correct relative path. Judging by your index.html file, I would consider trying '/resources/angular-app/popups/AddTrainingUser.html' instead.

Comment: Yes, I was trying second url too. I chenged template to templateUrl and firebug doesn't show any errors. In html sorces I can see my code but pop up is empty ...

Comment: Could you upload a sample of relevant source to fiddle?